# How do I properly achieve subtractive blending in C#, XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, blending, subtraction

I'm working on some kind of mod for **Terraria** (written in **C#** and using **XNA**), in which I need to use some blend modes. I didn't have any troubles getting additive blending to work, but subtractive one causes me some problems.
I managed to display stuff with subtractive blending, but it doesn't really want to return to the standard mode. *SpriteBatch.End* and *Begin* doesn't help at all.

This is my custom *BlendState*:

```
public readonly static BlendState
    bsSubtract = new BlendState{
        ColorSourceBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha,
        ColorDestinationBlend = Blend.One,
        ColorBlendFunction = BlendFunction.ReverseSubtract,
        AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha,
        AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.One,
        AlphaBlendFunction = BlendFunction.ReverseSubtract
    },
```

Drawing code:

```
sb.End();
sb.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate,bsSubtract);
(...drawing drawing blah...)
sb.End();
sb.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate,BlendState.Additive);
```

The problem is, everything that is drawn after this code seems to still use some old options (half-transparent, bland). What am I doing wrong?

I even tried calling just *sb.End()* and *sb.Begin()* before setting the blend state back, or using another custom blend state which was a standard additive one, just with *BlendFunctions* set to *Add*, to no avail.

EDIT: Seems like setting ANY custom BlendState makes it do that...

EDIT2: Seems like the problem was me splitting the drawing to 3 separate places: one for item slots, one for tiles and one for world in general. And in one of these (items) **I forgot** to set the SpriteBatch before using and reset it afterwards. I should have spent more time looking at my code. Still, thanks for trying to help!
(can't close the question just yet, gonna close it after StackOverflow lets me do it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem was me splitting the drawing to 3 separate places: one for item slots, one for tiles and one for world in general. And in one of these (items) **I forgot** to set the SpriteBatch before using and reset it afterwards. I should have spent more time looking at my code. Still, thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

**The default blending mode is `BlendState.AlphaBlend`.**

Try replacing `BlendState.Additive` with `BlendState.AlphaBlend` in your code. Or possibly `NonPremultiplied`, depending on what Terraria is actually using.

Better yet, you could read out *exactly* the blend state that Terraria was using, as `SpriteBatch` sets it on the graphics card and simply leaves it there. Here is some untested code that should do exactly that:

```
sb.End(); // Sets blend state
BlendState previousState = GraphicsDevice.BlendState; // Retrieve it
sb.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, bsSubtract);
// (...drawing drawing blah...)
sb.End();
sb.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, previousState); // Re-use it
```

Comment: The thing is, it's in a middle of sb.Begin() that I called myself, with additive blending set. I just need to draw something with subtractive blending and set it back to additive for the rest. Also, read my EDIT.